# How to place variables in url and submit form with php header

Tags: php

I am trying to place a variable in a url and submit the form automatically

I am doing a mysql select, and based on the results I need to do as explained above.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT prime_ID,
                        FROM School 
                        WHERE Date = (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)");

$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $SchoolId = $row["prime_ID"];


  header("Location:../SchoolList.php?school=" . $SchoolId . "&Submit=Submit");

}
?>
```

HTML of SchoolList.php

```
 $shoolid = $_GET['school'];
 <form method="POST" action="test.php">
        <input type="text" name="school" id="school" value="<?php echo $shoolid ?>">
        <br>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

The `SELECT` works but the form does not submit. The variable is also visible in the next page. Although the form redirect to `SchoolList.php`, the URL looks like this `SchoolList.php?school=45&Submit=Submit`

Why does it not submit `SchoolList.php`?

Comment: Where is `$shoolid` defined? You also shouldn't use `header` in the `while`, or if you are use and `exit` but that makes the loop pointless.

Comment: while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $SchoolId = $row["prime_ID"];

Comment: Your MySQL synatx ist broken due a ","

Comment: The select works. Just the submit part not working

Comment: @CharlesTester Do you want to go schoollist.php and submit the form automatically?

Comment: `SELECT prime_ID,` < no way that works.

Comment: how do you use the URL params? How do you know it's not submitting?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner. Typo. I simplified the select not to bore everyone with code that already works. The only issue is the submit

Comment: @user3783243 I made a new edit to include the code I left out. Let's see if gets accepted.

Comment: you would be surprised as to what people will post and we take posted code seriously. If you're going to simplify something, please don't include syntax errors, some may post an answer based on it, or the question being closed.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it gets stuck on SchoolList.php. SchoolList.php does not what it is suppose to

Comment: I think you should enable error reporting and check for errors on the query.

Comment: `<?php echo $shoolid ?>` where is that variable assigned? Again; error reporting said what? That's wrong for 2 reasons, should that be the actual variable name.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate. It is no where close the the same question

Comment: Could you clarify a few things here - assuming you have 3 scripts, one to get records to send from the School table, one with a form and then test.php - if you're looking to send a POST request to test.php with values from your School table, the way to do this is by using a CURL request (read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code ) -the header() redirect you're doing will actually only execute the _last_ request, not each of them. If you replace the header() with a curl request to test.php it should work if this is what you're trying to do?

Comment: @simandsim. I see that the comment part of the answer mention "sends a HTTP POST to a remote site", do I still need to include the code if test.php is on my server? Will it work if I have 10 results each needs to go to test.php with its unique variable?

Comment: Yes - you can still use your local server but you need to include the domain name for it too so something like `http://localhost/test.php` will do it, or the public domain name if you have one. For each record you have, you'll want to create a curl request, then it won't matter if you have 1 or 1,000 records, it will post each one individually and the curl request will wait until each is done before moving onto the next.

Answer (score -1):

You can use js with php. Add that code block to end of the body.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['Submit']))
{?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('formId').submit();
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

and your form (id added to form):

```
<form method="POST" id="formId" action="test.php">
        <input type="text" name="school" id="school" value="<?php echo $shoolid ?>">
        <br>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it is nto working

Comment: Can you check the form id is the same in html and js code? it should work. Is there an error on console?

Comment: With the original code no error on console. With the code above I get `
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null`

Comment: Did you add the id parameter to form? <form method="POST" **id="formId"** action="test.php"> And you added submit code after the form is it true?

Comment: Yes I did add the parameter

Comment: Where did you add the code? it should be after your form.